# How to prove that a function is a chord connecting two points

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, functions, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

I'm wondering of how to prove that
the function $h (\lambda) = \lambda f (x_1)+(1-\lambda) f(x_2)$ is geometrically depicted as a chord connecting
the points $(x_1, f (x_1))$ and $(x_2, f (x_2))$ in the Cartesian plane for any $x_1, x_2 \in X$ and any $\lambda\in [0, 1]$

if $f : X \to R$, with $X \subseteq R$.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Write $h$ as $h(\lambda) = (f(x_1) - f(x_2))\lambda + f(x_2)$, which shows  it is affine in $\lambda$, so it is a line ("chord"). Next, $h(0)=f(x_2)$ and $h(1) = f(x_1)$, so it connects the two points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $h$ as $h(\lambda)=(f(x_1)−f(x_2))\lambda+f(x_2)$, which shows it is affine in $\lambda$, so it is a line ("chord"). Next, $h(0)=f(x_2)$ and $h(1)=f(x_1)$, so it connects the two points.